# Difference between normal and array multiplication in surf()

Tags: matlab

In the following script, the matrix graph looks like noise.  what would cause the noise?

```
figure 
[x y] = meshgrid(-4:0.05:4); % Generate x and y data
axis([-3 3 -3 3 -3 3])
z = x.^2+y.^2; % Solve for z data
surf(x,y,z) %Plot the surface
figure
z = x^2+y^2; % Solve for z data
surf(x,y,z) %Plot the surface
```

Comment: Ho and by the way: in your second figure (with the matrix multiplication) `z`should be a zeros matrix, but due to the floating point errors you obtain those strange results

Comment: Thanks, also, how do revisions get approved? My original question was mislabeled as plot3 when it should have been surf. Now the question was revised to something I did not ask. Do I have the power to approve anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If x is a matrix, mathematically `x.^2` and `x^2` are two differents operations.

With `z = x.^2` you perform  an **element wise multiplication**

Which mean that every value in your matrix is going to be multiplicated by itself.

**Example:**

```
x =

   1   2
   3   4

x.^2 =

    1    4
    9   16
```

With `z = x^2` you perform a **matrix multiplication**

**Example:**

```
x =

    1   2
    3   4

x^2 =

    7   10
   15   22
```